# BorderLayout.CENTER doesn't center my JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, center

I have the following code to create my GUI.

```
private static void createGUI() {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Tiles Game");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  frame.setJMenuBar (new JMenuBar());
  frame.setContentPane (MainPanel.getInstance());

  frame.pack();
  frame.setResizable (false);
  frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
  frame.setVisible (true);
}
```

This is the MainPanel (extends JPanel) constructor:

```
private MainPanel() {
  super (new BorderLayout());
  setPreferredSize (new Dimension (IMG_SIZE + 10, IMG_SIZE + 10));
  ...
  panel = new ImagePanel();
  add (panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

And this is the ImagePanel (extends JPanel) constructor:

```
private ImagePanel() {
  super();
  setPreferredSize (new Dimension (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE));
  ...
}
```

However the ImagePanel is aligned to the top left corner of the MainPanel rather than centered, so I get a bunch of extra padding at the bottom and right sides, and none at the top and left sides. How do I place it at the center of the MainPanel?

Comment: It might be your image. Image has fixed size and if it's set to 0, 0 coordinates, every time you resize your JFrame it will look like your panel is not centered.

Comment: Try to set some visible border to your component if you have problems with alignment and you are not sure which component it causes. For example, put `this.setBorder(new EtchedBorder());` in your `MainPanel` constructor. You will then see the bounds it takes when initialised. As for your code, I see no problems with the layout - must be something else wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what's happening is that you are drawing your image from `(0, 0)` which are the top-left corner. Then you set the preferred size to 10 pixels larger which makes the panel larger, but the image is still at `(0, 0)`

Instead use the same size witoout adding 10, and just use an `EmptyBorder` for the panel. Also as a recommendation, override `getPreferredSize()` instead of using `setPreferredSize()`

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    public ImagePanel() {
        setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE);
    }
}
```

Also you may want to consider using a `GridBagLayout` for the container panel, for a sure center, if the container is to be larger than the the child panel. Few things you could do. Even consider using a `ImageIcon` and `JLabel` instead of painting (if the image doesn't need to be resized (as Camickr(+1) pointed out). A `JLabel` could easily be made a background by just setting the layout of the label and set it as the content pane of the frame.

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(...)
JLabel frameBackground = new JLabel(icon);
frameBackground.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.setContentPane(frameBackground);
```

Comment: So the problem was that BorderLayout doesn't respect preferred size (or even maximum size) and just resized the ImagePanel to fit the MainPanel. Using GridBagLayout properly centers my ImagePanel.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a JPanel to display an image.

Instead use a `JLabel` with an `ImageIcon`.

If you want extra space around the image then you use an `EmptyBorder` on the label.

Comment: I can't use ImageIcon, as I'm doing some image manipulation in there too. Is there a particular reason to use JLabel over JPanel?